# How to create User Account Setting in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, settings

I am new in Laravel & php . I have successfully created authentication in my laravel app. Now users can register and login to their account. Now i want to create an account settings option in my navbar which will redirect the users to a page where they will be able to change their name,email & password. Can anyone help me out how i will implement this ?

This is my Users table in DB

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->string('provider')->nullable();
            $table->string('provider_id')->nullable();
            $table->string('google_id')->nullable();
            $table->rememberToken()->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');
    }
}
```

Comment: define a route in your web.php for user settings account and add a middle ware auth for this route and then in your resources/views/layouts/app.blade.php add a link for user account settings.
make a separate controller or else use home controller and create function in that controller for account settings and in that function now implement your logic and do whatever you want to do.

Comment: but i am new in php so i dont know what functions do i have to write in  the code .:(

Comment: public function Account_Settings(Request $request){
   // perform your operations here
}

Comment: yes you have to write the code

Answer (score -1):

You have to implement User profile controller like this

For example :

```
class UsersController extends Controller
{
    //
    public function getList($message = null){
        $users = User::All();
        return view("users.list",Array("users"=>$users,"message"=>$message));
    }

    public function editUser($id){
        $user = User::findOrFail($id);
        return view("users.edit", Array("user"=>$user));
    }

    public function updateUser($id, Request $request){
        $user = User::findOrFail($id);

        if($request->input("name")!=null)$user->name = $request->input("name");
        if($request->input("email")!=email)$user->email = $request->input("email");

        $message = array("data"=>"User modified.","type"=>"success");
        try{
            $user->save();
        }catch(\Illuminate\Database\QueryException $ex){
            $message = array("data"=>"Exception trying modify the data ".$ex, "type"=>"danger");
        }
        return $this->getList($message);
    }

    public function changePassword($id){
        $user = User::findOrFail($id);
        return view("users.password", Array("user"=>$user));
    }

    public function updatePassword($id, Request $request){
        if($request->input("password") != $request->input("password_confirm"))
            return redirect()->back()->withInput()->with("message",Array("type"=>"danger","data"=>"Password fields does not match!"));

            $user = User::findOrFail($id);

            $user->password = bcrypt($request->input("password"));
            $message = array("data"=>"Password changed.","type"=>"success");

            try{
                $user->save();
            }catch(\Illuminate\Database\QueryException $ex){
                $message = array("data"=>"Exception trying modify the data ".$ex, "type"=>"danger");
            }
            return $this->getList($message);
    }

}
```